# What is idempotency in HTTP PUT? Can I disallow overwriting of a resource?

Tags: http, http-put, idempotent

I'm writing a REST API and I wish to allow authenticated users with the proper permissions to upload files via this API. I thought I'd use a `PUT` endpoint to handle this. I want to include a failsafe where the request will be rejected with a `400`-family error if the resource already exists and the user did not specify via a query that the resource should be overwritten (i.e. `PUT https://my.server.com/api/files/path/to/file.txt?overwrite=1`).

[The HTTP/1.1 RFC documentation of PUT](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) suggests that such a scenario is allowed:

> If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful completion of the request. If the resource could not be created or modified with the Request-URI, an appropriate error response SHOULD be given that reflects the nature of the problem.

But I'm hung up on the concept of idempotency. [The spec says](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.2):

> Methods can also have the property of "idempotence" in that (aside from error or expiration issues) the side-effects of N > 0 identical requests is the same as for a single request. The methods GET, HEAD, PUT and DELETE share this property. Also, the methods OPTIONS and TRACE SHOULD NOT have side effects, and so are inherently idempotent.
>
> However, it is possible that a sequence of several requests is non- idempotent, even if all of the methods executed in that sequence are idempotent. (A sequence is idempotent if a single execution of the entire sequence always yields a result that is not changed by a reexecution of all, or part, of that sequence.) For example, a sequence is non-idempotent if its result depends on a value that is later modified in the same sequence.
>
> A sequence that never has side effects is idempotent, by definition (provided that no concurrent operations are being executed on the same set of resources).

I can't wrap my head around this as it applies to my scenario. If `PUT https://my.server.com/myfile.txt` returns a `201 Created` the first time it's run, then a `403 Forbidden` or `409 Conflict` error without doing anything else on a subsequent request simply because the file already exists, does that violate the concept of idempotency? Does having to tack a query onto the URI to bypass the failsafe violate idempotency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common thinking mistake with idempotency.

The point of the rule is NOT that multiple identical requests get the same response.

The point of the rule is that if you send the same request multiple times, the state of the server is the same as if you only sent it once.

So if you send the same request twice, the second will error and get ignored, but the state on the server is still the same as if you only sent the first.

The updated HTTP standard has an [interesting note](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1) though:

> An origin server MUST NOT perform the requested method if a received
> If-Match condition evaluates to false; instead, the origin server
> MUST respond with either a) the 412 (Precondition Failed) status code
> or b) one of the 2xx (Successful) status codes if the origin server
> has verified that a state change is being requested and the final
> state is already reflected in the current state of the target
> resource (i.e., the change requested by the user agent has already
> succeeded, but the user agent might not be aware of it, perhaps
> because the prior response was lost or a compatible change was made
> by some other user agent).  In the latter case, the origin server
> MUST NOT send a validator header field in the response unless it can
> verify that the request is a duplicate of an immediately prior change
> made by the same user agent.

Even though that paragraph is specific to using the `If-Match` header, it might apply here too. Maybe you want to just return `201 Created` if you can detect that the exact same request was sent. That's kind of off-topic to your question though.

As an aside, you *should* use conditional headers instead of `?overwrite=1`. If you explicitly *don't* want to allow a client to update a resource if it has been created, the client can simply include:

```
If-None-Match: *
```

Then your server can return `412 Precondition Failed`, signaling the client that the resource was created earlier. Furthermore, if you want to force a client to always include this header, you can use `428 Precondition Required` to tell a client.

Comment: I've seen mention of server "state" before along these lines and it's served only to muddy my understanding further. What exactly is meant by "state" in the context of idempotency?

Comment: As an example, if you are building an API with a MySQL database, the 'state' would be the fact that a new record was created in mysql. It will get created on the first request, not the second.

Comment: @p0lar_bear added a ton of more background, hope it helps.

Comment: Oh! Alright, I get it now - it's not a matter of whether the response is the same, it's a matter of whether the data stored on the server has changed. Moreover, I had narrowed my scope of what constitutes a request too much, and forgot that the request body (i.e. the uploaded file) is a part of it - uploading the same exact file twice should have no impact on the data stored on the server.

Comment: You did not answer: Can I disallow overwriting of a resource?