# HTTP conditional PUT

Tags: http, http-put, idempotent

Reading the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954029/714104) to the question on [idempotency of HTTP PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953943/what-is-idempotency-in-http-put-can-i-disallow-overwriting-of-a-resource) I learned about an interesting aspect of conditional PUT requests which lead to the following question.

The specification on HTTP Conditional requests defines in [section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1):

> An origin server MUST NOT perform the requested method if a received
> If-Match condition evaluates to false; instead, the origin server
> MUST respond with either a) the 412 (Precondition Failed) status code
> or b) one of the 2xx (Successful) status codes if the origin server
> has verified that a state change is being requested and the final
> state is already reflected in the current state of the target
> resource (i.e., the change requested by the user agent has already
> succeeded, but the user agent might not be aware of it, perhaps
> because the prior response was lost or a compatible change was made
> by some other user agent).  In the latter case, the origin server
> MUST NOT send a validator header field in the response unless it can
> verify that the request is a duplicate of an immediately prior change
> made by the same user agent.

Conditional PUT requests are used to avoid the lost update problem when multiple agents are acting in parallel on the same resource (using optimistic locking).
Let us assume the value of a resource is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
ETag: "0"

{ "value": 0 }
```

Now two clients simultaneously want to increment the value and send a `PUT` request with a body which contains the new value, together with an `If-Match` header.

```
PUT /value HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
If-Match: "0“
    
{ "value": 1 }
```

The server answers on the first request with status `200` (`OK`) and on the second one with status `412` (`Precondition Failed`), i.e. the second client has to repeat his task (GET, update resource and PUT it with an `If-Match` header with the new etag value).

Now let’s assume that both clients did not receive the answer and therefore both send the request again (obviously they *must* use the same `If-Match` header). According to the spec, the server MUST return the same status codes, i.e. `200` to the first and `412` to the second. If the server would return `200` to both, an update would be lost, and if the server would return `412` to both, then both clients would start over and the value would be 3 at the end.

My question is how this can be implemented on server-side. I see the need that the server must store a history of all state changes together with an identification of the client. But how would the client be identified? Would a combination of the client-ip and the User-Agent header be enough?

Are there (Java) libraries which implement this behavior out of the box?
It is also not clear to me which validator header field must not be sent to the client.

Comment: I don't get where you see the problem. The server has the current state of the resource (metadata such as ETag and content). That's sufficient to process the conditional request.

Comment: Hi @JulianReschke, thanks for your comments! The server has the new state `{ "value": 1}` with the new etag "1" and would, without special treatment, return `412 Precondition Failed` on both resent requests with the consequence, that both clients start over, get the current state with the new etag, change the data and update the data. The spec specifies that in this case 200 must be returned to the first caller and 412 to the second caller, i.e. the server must keep the history of all transitions together with a reference to the client. Did I understand that right, and how is this implemented?

Comment: I still don't understand why you'd need a history. The current state is completely suffcient. The fact that both clients would get a 412 IMHO is not an issue. Why optimize for an edge case?

Comment: I use conditional put to implement optimistic locking. In the simple example above, both clients try to increment the value using optimistic locking. If both clients would get a 412 as result on their resend, then both clients would start over and query the value (together with the current etag), increment it and update the value on the server. Finally the value stored on the server would be `{ "value" : 3}' which would be wrong as the inc operation were applied three times. The spec cited above states, that the server must handle this case, so I do not want to optimize but follow the spec.

Comment: The spec doesn't make the requirement you seem to assume. Losing the response to a succesful request IMHO is an absolute edge case. So yes, it you do conditional PUT requests to update a counter you'll end up with an additional update.

Comment: if the server, in case that the If-Match header does not match, would only check whether the requested state is already reflected in the current state and would return 2xx in this case, then optimistic locking would not work. Therefore the spec notes that 2xx is only returned if the change is requested *by the user agent* has already succeeded, so the answer is user agent specific, right?